# coc diagnostic signs displaying incorrectly

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

[My coc settings](https://github.com/ajr-dev/dotfiles/blob/master/config/nvim/coc-settings.json) are practically copied and pasted from [nicknisi/dotfiles](https://github.com/nicknisi/dotfiles/blob/master/config/nvim/coc-settings.json). I'm using SourceCodePro from Nerd Fonts.

```
{
    "suggest.enablePreview": true,
    "codeLens.enable": true,
    "git.addedSign.text": "┃",
    "git.removedSign.text": "┃",
    "git.changedSign.text": "┃",
    "git.changeRemovedSign.text": "┃",
    "suggest.maxPreviewWidth": 100,
    "diagnostic.checkCurrentLine": true,
    "diagnostic.maxWindowHeight": 20,
    "diagnostic.errorSign": "✖",
    "diagnostic.warningSign": "⚠",
    "diagnostic.infoSign": "●",
    "diagnostic.hintSign": "○",
    "git.addGBlameToBufferVar": true,
    "coc.preferences.formatOnSaveFiletypes": ["typescript", "javascript", "javascript.jsx", "typescript.tsx", "typescriptreact", "javascriptreact", "html"],
    "explorer.icon.enableNerdfont": true,
    "explorer.sources": [
        {"name": "buffer", "expand": true},
        {"name": "file", "expand": true}
    ],
    "explorer.git.icon.status.added": "✚",
    "explorer.git.icon.status.deleted": "✖",
    "explorer.git.icon.status.renamed": "➜",
    "explorer.git.icon.status.unmerged": "═",
    "explorer.git.icon.status.untracked": "?",
    "explorer.git.icon.status.modified": "✹",
    "explorer.git.icon.status.ignored": "☒",
    "explorer.openAction.for.directory": "expandOrCollapse",
    "explorer.previewAction.onHover": false,
    "explorer.keyMappings.global": {
        "<cr>": ["expandable?", ["expanded?", "collapse", "expand"], "open"]
    },
    "eslint.autoFixOnSave": false,
    "eslint.autoFix": false,
    "diagnostic-languageserver.filetypes": {
        "sh": "shellcheck"
    },
    "diagnostic-languageserver.linters": {
        "shellcheck": {
            "args": [
                "--format=gcc",
                "--external-sources",
                "-"
            ],
            "command": "shellcheck",
            "debounce": 100,
            "formatLines": 1,
            "formatPattern": [
                "^[^:]+:(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+([^:]+):\\s+(.*)$",
                {
                    "column": 2,
                    "line": 1,
                    "message": 4,
                    "security": 3
                }
            ],
            "offsetColumn": 0,
            "offsetLine": 0,
            "securities": {
                "error": "error",
                "note": "warning",
                "warning": "warning"
            },
            "sourceName": "shellcheck"
        }
    },
    "suggest.completionItemKindLabels": {
        "keyword": "\uf1de",
        "variable": "\ue79b",
        "value": "\uf89f",
        "operator": "\u03a8",
        "constructor": "\uf0ad",
        "function": "\u0192",
        "reference": "\ufa46",
        "constant": "\uf8fe",
        "method": "\uf09a",
        "struct": "\ufb44",
        "class": "\uf0e8",
        "interface": "\uf417",
        "text": "\ue612",
        "enum": "\uf435",
        "enumMember": "\uf02b",
        "module": "\uf40d",
        "color": "\ue22b",
        "property": "\ue624",
        "field": "\uf9be",
        "unit": "\uf475",
        "event": "\ufacd",
        "file": "\uf723",
        "folder": "\uf114",
        "snippet": "\ue60b",
        "typeParameter": "\uf728",
        "default": "\uf29c"
    }
}
```

CocInfo gives:

```
vim version: NVIM v0.4.4
node version: v16.4.1
coc.nvim version: 0.0.80-131f6b267f
coc.nvim directory: /home/user/.dotfiles/config/nvim/plugged/coc.nvim
term: tmux
platform: linux

## Log of coc.nvim

2021-07-06T20:36:32.411 INFO (pid:204314) [services] - registered service "languageserver.go"
2021-07-06T20:36:32.438 INFO (pid:204314) [services] - registered service "diagnostic-languageserver"
2021-07-06T20:36:32.460 INFO (pid:204314) [services] - registered service "eslint"
2021-07-06T20:36:32.688 INFO (pid:204314) [services] - registered service "highlight"
2021-07-06T20:36:32.825 INFO (pid:204314) [plugin] - coc.nvim 0.0.80-131f6b267f initialized with node: v16.4.1 after 511ms
2021-07-06T20:36:33.129 INFO (pid:204314) [attach] - receive notification: highlight []
2021-07-06T20:36:36.234 INFO (pid:204314) [attach] - receive notification: showInfo []
```

Right now I'm seeing this:
[image]

I'd like to know how to set it like one of the following:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wasn't this very recently posted?

Comment: Haven't I seen you posting this question over and over for the past few days? If you want someone to answer you should keep your question open otherwise at this point this is becoming spam.

Comment: how about asking at the coc repository for support?

Comment: Yes, I'll try that.